# Submanifold, Tangent Space.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Show that

(1)
M= $ \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ :$ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} - 3xyz = 1 \}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

(2) Compute the Tangent Space of M at $a$, for $a \in M$.

Attempt(1) If I define $f$ such that $f(x,y,z) = x^{2} + y^{2}+z^{2} - 3xyz $

Then if $\Delta(f) \ne 0$ then M is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

If I let it $= 0$ i get,

$x = (3/2) yz$

$y= (3/2)xz$

$z= (3/2)xy$

(2) I am stuck here and finding it hard to get notes to help (or notes I can understand).

$T_{a}M$ is the set of all derivations on all of the equivalence classes in $C^{\infty} (M,a)$. Do I have to create another map that agrees on $M$?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: for $x^2+y^2+z^2-3xyz=1$ you oughta think in terms of a **level surface**

Comment: Your proof of (1) is incorrect. Use janmarqz' comment.

Comment: it is known that for a function $f=f(x,y,z)$ the ${\rm grad}f$ is a perpendicular direction to the tangent space of level surface

Comment: because it is a level set we can say that it is a regular submanifold?

Comment: @Sean, meanwhile the ${\rm grad}$ be non zero, that is true

Comment: @janmarqz can you explain a bit more clearly please? thanks for the help.

Comment: ok, I will illustrate as an answer

Comment: @Sean, already done... please let me know if the (semi)-answer there, clarify the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient is 
$${\rm grad}\ f(x,y,z)=[2x-3yz,2y-3xz,2z-3xy],$$ 
which is $[0,0,0]$ iff $x=0,y=0,z=0$.

Since this critical point is not in the level surface then the surface is regular.

Let us take a point in the level surface $f^{-1}(1)$, let say 
$a=(1,1,\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2})$.

We get ${\rm grad}\ f(a)=[-\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2},-\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt 5}{2}]$.

Then the equation for a plane, tangent to the level surface at $a$, is 
$$-\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}x-\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}y+\frac{-3+\sqrt 5}{2}z=C$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: thank you, yes that clears things up. can I take any a that satisfies M, i.e (0,0.1) ?

Comment: mmh... if $f(0,0,1)=1$ the answer would be yes

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I can just write using a general $a = (a1,a2,a3)$ that satisfies $ f(a1,a2,a3) = 1$

Comment: the formula for the tangent plane should be ${\rm grad}\ f(a_1,a_2,a_3)\bullet(x-a_1,y-a_2,z-a_3)=0$

Comment: do you already see the plot of such surface? see it at https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/level-surface/

Comment: no I have never seen what it looks like, thank you.